# Rename file name with javascript expression

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, split, string-concatenation

I'm fairly new to javascript and I need to rename or add to an extension of a css and .png file.  The script is embedded within an ETL process.  I have a variable "prd" that holds the value of the file name that the style.css and picture.png file are derived from and I also need to add a date or time stamp to the end of the extension.  Basically I'm wanting to concatenate `prd+style_02_06_14.png`

Desired results:

```
Prd = sales_report   
File = style.css.      
Result = "sales_report_style_02_06_14.png" and "sales_report_style_02_06_14.css"
```

Here is my code

```
var sourceCssFile = outputfolder + "style.css";
var destinationCssFile = outputfolder + css_pic;

if(isFolder(destinationCssFile) == false) {
    createFolder(destinationCssFile);
    var testvar = "inside";
}

destinationCssFile = destinationCssFile + "/style.css";


moveFile(sourceCssFile, destinationCssFile, true);

var sourceImageFile = outputfolder + "picture.png";
var destinationImageFile = outputfolder + css_pic + "/picture.png";
moveFile(sourceImageFile, destinationImageFile, true);

var cont = loadFileContent(output);
var replaceCss = css_pic + "tt+style.css";
var replaceImg = css_pic + "tt + picture.png";
cont = cont.replace("style.css", replaceCss);
cont = cont.replace("picture.png", replaceImg);
var filename = outputfolder + new_str;
```

Comment: How can you read your code when you format it like that?

Comment: Are you using Node?  You can't do file access with JavaScript from within a browser....

Comment: Using Pentaho Sppon.  It's a javascript transformation within a process.  Etl process pulls Pentaho report, converts to html, distributes the images and style sheet to a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function formatResult(prd, filename, date, extension) {
    return prd + '_' + filename + '_' + formatDate(d) + '.' + extension;
}

function formatDate(d) {
    var year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);

    var month = (d.getMonth()+1) + '';
    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    var day = d.getDate() + '';
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    return month + '_' + day + '_' + year;
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/WHpuU/5/

#### Nota

```
alert( 'style.css'.replace(/\.css$/i, '') ); // shows 'style'
```